# Detect any applications running in foreground

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there anyway to detect any applications running in foreground? I wanted to perform some actions whenever the user in the home screen. If the user is in Email or other activity, I don't want to trigger those actions.

Comment: Clarify your question - you stated *I wanted to perform some actions...* yet the closing statement *I don't want to trigger those actions* appears contradictory...

Comment: [this may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393908/how-to-get-any-identifier-of-the-topmost-activity)