# How to check which activity is showing on screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to check which activity is on the front, from a class that is no activity (that's just another class that does some actions for me, but not bounded with any activity).

How can I check from this class which activity is actually showing on the screen?

Comment: Please elaborate. I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Nothing understand. please be specific about your issue in your question..dude

Comment: It sounds like really bad practice what you are trying to do :S

Comment: I need only name of activity which is actually showing, but not in this activity, but in class with some methods, which is not activity

Comment: Use a stack inside a singleton, put on onCreate and pop on onDestoy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393908/how-to-get-any-identifier-of-the-topmost-activity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) to get this. Following is the sample code:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


 // get the info from the currently running task
 List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

 Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

 ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
 String packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

You will need the following permission on your manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
```

[Source](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/getting-info-about-your-currently-running-activities/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create in a custom Application object a member called "Activity lastActivityShown" and in all onCreate of all Activities you can `getApplication().setLastActivityShown(this)` in this way you dont need permissions. You can also create a BaseActivity that have this logic and get all Activities extends this.