# Check which application launched?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I am wondering how one can check that which application is launched in android. For example, when some game is launched or browser is opened, my application gets to know that this very application is launched. Is there anyway to find this thing out?

Comment: Have You tried this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393908/how-to-get-any-identifier-of-the-topmost-activity and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service?

Answer (score 0):

this   code  is check service is launched,i think  that is very likely with activity

```
ActivityManager activityManager=(ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningServiceInfo> list= activityManager.getRunningServices(70);
```