# Find out where activity was started from

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I have a button which is drawn from a service (using `windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);` ) This button is visible throughout the device (till the service is stopped)

Clicking on this button starts an activity A (using intent flag ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK). I want to know if it is possible to find out where this button was pressed? (the location of the activity where the user was while pressing the button)

I need to know this because in activity A , there is a button called GO BACK, which should return the user to the exact position where he was initially.

**Note, due to some reasons, I cant call `finish();`**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Dynamicly Get the Current Activity in Foreground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115493/android-dynamicly-get-the-current-activity-in-foreground)

Comment: all you have to do is that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115493/android-dynamicly-get-the-current-activity-in-foreground the moment the user click the button and put on the intent.

Comment: Will it work if the user is in the device's home screen ?

Comment: the device home screen is an activity just like any other.