# How to show alertdialog from another class and handle it in Current Activity(Android)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-notifications

I am sending notification on certain occurrence and notify user via notification if app is in background and via alert if user is in **foreground**. Now I wonder how to show alert dialog from **my notification class** and handle that **dialog** in **Current Activity**.

Please Guide me on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: here is my Answer ! , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393908/how-to-get-any-identifier-of-the-topmost-activity/26308339#26308339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up an Intent and a Broadcast Receiver.  That will allow you to broadcast and intent from your notification activity and if your app is in the foreground, then the broadcast receiver configured in the app can pick it up and display a dialog.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: No problem!  If you feel a little lost in the whole broadcast receiver thing, let us know and if you provide some code maybe we can help.  Once you understand it, they are very, very easy.

Comment: Yeah It seems like very tough to understand at first glance.

Answer (score 4):

This will Work by sending context to another activity

```
public class Message {

 public static void alert_msg(Context context, String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Set Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Set Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);


    // Set OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    // Show Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
 }
}
```

call using this

```
  Message.alert_msg(MainActivity.this,"Title","Your Message Here");
```

Comment: Ok.Thanks .But I got error on MainActivity.this.How can I pass My activity to Message.alert_msg argument?

Comment: you have to just pass context to that method...placed in come another class .

Comment: Ok.I did as you said but it gave me error as ARCA caught a badtoken exception for my bundle on line of alertDialog.show().

Answer (score 0):

-> by passing  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() object in parameters and implementing it in Activity class

```
AlertDialogs alertdialog;

    alertdialog.SingleSelectDialog("title",otherParameters,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          int x=alertdialog.getAmount();

                        }
                    });
```

-> in class AlertDialogs

```
        public void SingleSelectWithImage(String head,otherParameters, DialogInterface.OnClickListener pressok) {
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle(head);

              amount=bla_bla;    
               //do anything
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", pressok);
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        dialogBuilder.show();        

}
```

-> getter method

```
 public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
```