# Finish activity in dialog class

Tags: android, dialog, activity-finish

In my `MainActivity` I call

```
 MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(MainActivity.this);
 dialog.show();
```

`MyDialog` is my own class where I customize the dialog.
In the dialog is a button. I want that the `MainActivity` and the dialog finishes/dissappears when the button is pressed, because I start another Activity then.
How can I say in the `MyDialog` class, in the `onClickListener`, that the `MainActivity` should `finish()`?

Shortened code of my dialog:

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

    void onClick() {
        Intent menu = new Intent(getContext(), Menu.class);
        getContext().startActivity(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your dialog code.

Comment: There is no finis() if I say MainActivity in the dialog class

Comment: The dialog code is bit too long but I have:
public class myDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{}
and in the onClick method I call:
Intent menu = new Intent(getContext(), menu.class);
getContext().startActivity(menu);
and there I want to finish the MainActivity and the dialog.

Comment: take a look At this ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393908/how-to-get-any-identifier-of-the-topmost-activity/26308339#26308339

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can finish your Activity as below...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourSecondActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
((Activity) context).finish();
```

**Update:**

In your constructor of you custom dialog class, get the activity context as below...

```
Context mContext;

public myDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

then in your `onClick()` method finish the activity as below...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent menu = new Intent(mContext, menu.class);
    mContext.startActivity(menu);
    ((Activity) mContext).finish();
}
```

Comment: Then he gives me a NullPointerException at the Intent menu = new Intent(mContext, menu.class); line

Comment: did you initialoze the `mContext` as I suggest?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly in your dialog class pass the context of the caller activities say MainActivit.class **context**

Now first close the dialog

```
//so as to avoid the window leaks as on destroying the activity it's context would also get vanished.
    dialog.dismiss();
```

and then

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Comment: How can I do this:
"pass the context of the caller activities say MainActivit.class context"?

Comment: @Lars3n95 yes say you are using the dialog class from MainActivity then u create a constructor in dialog class with argument as Context context. Now use this context every where in class to create the dialog and finish the current activity.